# Handle Bulk API load with MuleSoft

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I am new to Mulesoft. I have an api in my application which can't handle more than 2000 parallel requests. I am thinking to use Mulesoft as a proxy API which takes the request and hit my API so that even if my API reaches its capacity Mulesoft will pause for sometime and hit my API without loosing any data.

Does Mulesoft solve my issue? if so can anyone please guide me through the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably would want something as simple as the `until-successful` scope. You can read up more about that [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/until-successful-scope). The premise of it is this:

You wrap a component in the `until-successful` scope, and you define the following:

- What how a failure is defined or how a success is defined
- How many times you want to try the component until an overall failure,
- How much time should elapse between each call.

There are examples in the documentation that I linked to and those should help guide you!

Answer (score 0):

1. What is peak load (no.of requests) your application API is expecting to handle ?
2. Mule API proxy can be used for response caching here. This means for similar reuests, your API wont get hit , the responses would be sent back from  proxy itself. But this alone may not ,probably solve the load issue.

You might have to do the load balancing of your API depending on the peak load requirement.